# confusion over designing options for dashboard

Tags: css, user-interface, bootstrap-4

I have 7 different options for our machines which i put on top of the page to give the user options to find out what's going on in their machines,what I have created is below
[image: options]

shows how many machines are in which status, but there are two issues with it(as far as know) they are occupied a lot of space, I have no idea whats the best way to show these? I know there is no unique way but at least i want to get some insight,i wa thinking to put a simple button with a badge like below :

```
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
             All <span class="badge badge-light">236</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">
             Run <span class="badge badge-light">4</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
             STOP <span class="badge badge-light">4</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
             Data_Incomplete <span class="badge badge-light">33</span>
        </button>
```

but the problem is, depends on the text length on it the size becomes different, any idea will be appreciated

Comment: If the size gets messed up based on the content of the text then you can give a fixed width to the text container, then add ellipsis. When the user hovers on the ellipsis, you can show a tooltip with the entire text data.

Comment: @NigelDcruz you mean the button approach is fine?